# Why I am getting this output on screen while the file I am writing to is fine?

Tags: java, io

Sample code is :-

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class CopyBytes {

    public static void main(String [] args){
    CopyBytes obj = new CopyBytes();
    File file = new File("/home/mount/Data/JAVA/xanadu.bak");
    obj.copyBytes(file);
    }

    public void copyBytes(File ifile){
    FileInputStream reader = null;
    FileOutputStream output =null;
    int c=0;
    try{
    reader = new FileInputStream(ifile);
    output = new FileOutputStream("outfile");
    while((c = reader.read()) != -1)
    {
        System.out.print(c);
        output.write(c);
    }   
        System.out.println();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException fnfex){
    fnfex.getMessage();
    fnfex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException ioex){
    ioex.getMessage();
    ioex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
    if(reader !=null)
    {
        System.out.println("Closing the Stream");
        try{
        reader.close();
        System.out.println("Closed the Streams");
        }
        catch(IOException ioex)
        {
            ioex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else{
    System.out.println("Stream not open");
    }
}
}
}
```

Contents of the `xanadu.bak` are as follows:-

```
buffer@ankit:/home/mount/Data/JAVA/practice/src/fileio.bytestreams.com$ cat /home/mount/Data/JAVA/xanadu.bak
IA
```

When above code is run;it gives following output:

buffer@ankit:/home/mount/Data/JAVA/practice/src/fileio.bytestreams.com$ java CopyBytes

```
736510
Closing the Stream
Closed the Streams
```

whereas i should get

```
7365
Closing the Stream
Closed the Streams
```

The file to which I am writing is perfectly fine. Please provide your valuable inputs.

Comment: Your file has a new-line at the end.

Comment: @Mat, thanks for your answer; but I didn't include new-line character in my file.If I open a file in an editor then there isn't a new line character which can be deleted.

Comment: Editors very often add one. Use `hexdump` or something like that to see what's _really_ in your file.

Comment: @Mat, you could please add your comment as answer so that I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last character printed is `10`<sub>d</sub>, or `0x0A`. That's a newline character. Other combinations like  `0x0D 0x0A` or the reverse could happen on other platforms.

A lot of editors add a newline at the end of files if there isn't one, and that's what you're seeing.

Use something like `hexdump` to ascertain what your file *really* contains.
<sub>You code works pretty well for that too :-)</sub>